# How to make button open a link in new tab in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a `<button>` that when clicked will open a URL in a new tab.

This is easy to achieve in pure HTML, but the catch is that the `<button>` is dynamically generated, thus this has to be done in JavaScript.

This is the code I used to create a `<button>` so far using JavaScript and HTML DOM:

```
<body>
  <div id = 'only_div'>
  </div>
  <script>
    var btn=document.createElement("button");
    btn.innerText = "Click me";
    document.getElementById("only_div").appendChild(btn);
  </script>
</body>
```

In this existing code, I just want to add that when clicked, a URL (for example `http://www.stackoverflow.com`) will open in a new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following, which will open the tab in a new tab and go to this tab:

```
function openInNewTab(url) {
  const win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}

const btn=document.createElement("button");
btn.innerText = "Click me";
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    openInNewTab('http://www.test.com')
});
document.getElementById("only_div").appendChild(btn);
```

See [js fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/h0yu5sL2/).

Comment: It worked! But many people provided with may correct answers. What is the policy on SO, which answer to accept as the correct one?

Comment: this answer was the first one, and it does what you asked so this should probably be the accepted one, but who knows ‍♂️up to you

Answer (score 5):

You can add a `click` event listener to the button with `addEventListener()` and  then when it's trigger use `window.location.replace()` to redirect.

```
<body>
    <div id = 'only_div'>
    </div>

    <script>
      var btn=document.createElement("button");
      btn.innerText = "Click me";
      btn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
         window.location.replace(URL);
      });
      document.getElementById("only_div").appendChild(btn);
    </script>

</body>
```

for a new tab use:

```
window.open(URL, '_blank');
```

**Docs:**

- [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)
- [open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: This works but unfortunately, it doesn't open the URL in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply add

`btn.onclick = function() { // Note this is a function
    window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com/', '_blank');
};`

and that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to attach the event (*click*) to the button. You can do so by using [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). You can use [`Window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) to *load the specified resource into the browsing context.*

Your code should be like the following:

```
var btn=document.createElement("button");
btn.innerText = "Click me";
// attach the event
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com', '_blank'); // _blank will open the site in a new tab
});
document.getElementById("only_div").appendChild(btn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`setAttribute()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp):

```
btn.setAttribute("onclick","window.open('https://stackoverflow.com','_blank')");
```